# Differentiation of products

Tags: calculus, derivatives, products

Find the derivative for

$$(\sqrt{3x} - \sqrt[3]{x})^3 (x+3)^{1/3}.$$

I'd tried to use the formula $f'(x) = u'(x)v(x) + v'(x)u(x)$, but it become very complicated. It will produce many fraction and I cannot solve for that.

Comment: So many questions asked, it's high time you learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Logarithmic differentiation would make life easier $$y=(\sqrt{3x} - \sqrt[3]{x})^3 (x+3)^{1/3}$$ $$\log(y)=3\log(\sqrt{3x} - \sqrt[3]{x})+\frac 13\log(x+3)$$ Differentiate $$\frac{y'}y=3 \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{3 x^{2/3}}}{\sqrt{3}
   \sqrt{x}-\sqrt[3]{x}}+\frac 13 \frac 1 {x+3}$$ Simplify and, later, $y'=y\times\frac{y'}y$.